# Error: cannot find module hdwallet-provider - trying to deploy contract to ropsten using infura key

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-migration, infura

I have reviewed the other posts in the last few days following what seem like forever for get to sync to my local machine - so this is my last try to get it to deploy the petshop contract to ropsten via using a key from infura as suggested by someone as the sync in ropsten is taking too long.

I have reconfigured my `truffle.js` to use an infura key but when

I run the command to deploy I get the `cannot find module truffle-hdwallet-provider` - (see screenshot below)

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated -

```
Update:  
npm uninstall ethereumjs-wallet
npm uninstall truffle-hdwallet-provider
npm install --save ethereumjs-wallet@0.6.0
npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.3
```

[image]

my truffle script is below - I have grey out the key for obvious reasons :)

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const MNEMONIC = '*******************************************************';

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/*****************************")
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 4000000      //make sure this gas allocation isn't over 4M, which is the max
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: The error messages indicates it can't find a python executable. One of the dependencies requires python 2.7 to be installed, check the [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency). It will also require a C++ compiler make sure it is installed.